# Rename font using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to rename font using itextsharp
I have Managed to rename the font in the pdf using the following code

```
        PdfName baseFont = dict.GetAsName(PdfName.BASEFONT);            
        if (baseFont.GetBytes()[7] == '+')
        {
            string rename = baseFont.ToString().Substring(8);

            string temp = baseFont.ToString().Replace(rename, "Changed" + cnt).Replace("/", "");
            baseFont = new PdfName(temp);                
            dict.Put(PdfName.BASEFONT, baseFont);
            cnt++;
        }

        PdfDictionary fontDescriptor = dict.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR);
        PdfDictionary Encoding = dict.GetAsDict(PdfName.ENCODING);


        if (fontDescriptor == null)
            return;
        fontDescriptor.Put(PdfName.FONTNAME, baseFont);
```

by using the above code i am able to change the font name in acrobat document property.

but old name is visible when i select the text using edit text and image using acrobat 10

Comment: Probably the embedded font program itself contains the name. As you don't share the PDF, it is hard to tell.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a good reason to do this in the first place and I can't come up with anything. One option is that someone created a PDF with _Comic Sans_ and you want it to look the same but say _Arial_. Another is that you're thinking of a PDF as a web page and you're hoping to not just _rename_ the font but actually _change_ it. The last option is that you're trying to, for whatever reason, hide the name of the original font used. If possible, all of these would better be suited to do beforehand instead of afterwards.